# How can I decrease space between bootstrap columns (only between not on the outsides)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, styles

I have some bootstrap columns like this:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <a href="gallerij/stockfotos/boeken" class="catphotowrap">
        <div class="catphotodiv">
            <img class="galleryicon" src="website/images/category_icons/8dxVaqo1QlsfhsHnsb0yeCTwwhoIZqBcW80lEJNn.svg" />
            <h2>Boeken</h2>
            <div class="catphotooverlay"></div>
            <img class="gallerybgimg" src="website/images/photos/previews/preview-003fafb080bd3f96d74fbdef3fa1a859.jpg" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <a href="gallerij/stockfotos/bomen" class="catphotowrap">
        <div class="catphotodiv">
            <img class="galleryicon" src="website/images/category_icons/XJl6AVsrwNULvmVwGuiKtXazlB1Fso6NuKIet8Ld.svg" />
            <h2>Bomen</h2>
            <div class="catphotooverlay"></div>
            <img class="gallerybgimg" src="website/images/photos/previews/preview-6c1b01bd43c5ee53d802d6f67a32927f.jpg" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <a href="gallerij/stockfotos/details" class="catphotowrap">
        <div class="catphotodiv">
            <img class="galleryicon" src="website/images/category_icons/yReYovclETiF7xQnMHNi4Df9kqyyqWMOErm8DYvB.svg" />
            <h2>Details</h2>
            <div class="catphotooverlay"></div>
            <img class="gallerybgimg" src="website/images/photos/previews/preview-a00b406c81ebe322e7d9469e98c9c200.jpg" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <a href="gallerij/stockfotos/dieren" class="catphotowrap">
        <div class="catphotodiv">
            <img class="galleryicon" src="website/images/category_icons/nr8FkeGgoQ9tmZIy7r5xOHOPbFbvvIm52nm6tQHm.svg" />
            <h2>Dieren</h2>
            <div class="catphotooverlay"></div>
            <img class="gallerybgimg" src="website/images/photos/previews/preview-1448fdfe351cc3e2a5a6b8d5e3870349.jpg" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <a href="gallerij/stockfotos/eten" class="catphotowrap">
        <div class="catphotodiv">
            <img class="galleryicon" src="website/images/category_icons/Nuncyz8P5mELHI1dfqfvYqDUhGJhvtY2p5Ce99lO.svg" />
            <h2>Eten</h2>
            <div class="catphotooverlay"></div>
            <img class="gallerybgimg" src="website/images/photos/previews/preview-324d6f2bba88af612e8bae3e9df7c4d1.jpg" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

But on mobile there is too much space as you can see here:

[image]

How can I decrease space between columns, (the red lines). I found questions on SO on how to remove them or how to increase/decrease padding all around the columns. I want to decrease the padding only between the columns.

How can I do that? I am using bootstrap 4.

I found out about offset classes like `offset-md-*` but this increases the space while I want to decrease the space.

Answer (score 0):

Set all child to 100% with of the parent which is column are else use css Grid layout where you can give space x and y directions

Answer (score 0):

you can set row gutter(space between the column) by using .gx-(value) class in that particular row.

Answer (score -1):

Wich version of bootstrap are you using? You can read about gutters.

for version 5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/

or

for version 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Regards